# Can't enumerate getters/setters properties

Tags: javascript, reflection

I am working on some reflections code to try to scrape out properties and functions, but I can't seem to get the getters/setters at all.

The reflection code I have for properties is:

```
Reflector = function() { };

Reflector.getProperties = function(obj) {
  var properties = [];
  var proto = obj;
  while (proto != Object.prototype) {
    console.log('Scrapping proto: ', proto);
    for (var prop in proto) {
      console.log('typeof ' + prop + ": ", typeof obj[prop]);
      if (typeof obj[prop] != 'function') {
        properties.push(prop);
      }
    }
    proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto);
  }
  return properties;
};
```

And a sample of it running (with my debug messages) is:

```
var SimpleTestObject = function() {
  this.value = "Test1";
  this._hiddenVal = "Test2";
  this._readOnlyVal = "Test3";
  this._rwVal = "Test4";
};
SimpleTestObject.prototype = {
  get readOnlyVal() {
    return this._readOnlyVal;
  },
  get rwVal() {
    return this._rwVal;
  },
  set rwVal(value) {
    this._rwVal = value;
  },
  func1: function() {
    // Test
  }
};
SimpleTestObject.func2 = function(test) { /* Test */ };
SimpleTestObject.outsideVal = "Test5";

var props = Reflector.getProperties(SimpleTestObject);
console.log('props: ', props);
console.log('Object.getOwnPropertyNames: ', Object.getOwnPropertyNames(SimpleTestObject));
console.log('rwVal property descriptor: ', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(SimpleTestObject, 'rwVal'));
console.log('rwVal (2) property descriptor: ', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(SimpleTestObject), 'rwVal'));
```

What I expect to see as output to my `Reflection.getProperties(SimpleTestObject)` is `['readOnlyVal', 'rwVal', 'outsideVal']`, but instead I am only seeing `outsideVal`.  Further, when I tried to using `getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` to see if the `rwVal` was enumerable, it came back as undefined.  So, thinking maybe it somehow got showed into the prototype above, I tried going up a level and still got undefined.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that it works like this. Anyone else have any work arounds?

Answer (score 3):

For enumerate the getters please use Object.keys or Object.getOwnPropertiesNames on prototype instead of constructor or/and instance:

```js
function readGetters(obj) {
    var result = [];
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((property) => {
        var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, property);
        if (typeof descriptor.get === 'function') {
            result.push(property);
        }
    });
    return result;
}



var SimpleTestObject = function() {
    this.value = "Test1";
    this._hiddenVal = "Test2";
    this._readOnlyVal = "Test3";
    this._rwVal = "Test4";
};
SimpleTestObject.prototype = {
    get readOnlyVal() {
        return this._readOnlyVal;
    },
    get rwVal() {
        return this._rwVal;
    },
    set rwVal(value) {
        this._rwVal = value;
    },
    func1: function() {

    }
};
SimpleTestObject.func2 = function(test) { /* Test */ };
SimpleTestObject.outsideVal = "Test5";


// For constructor
console.log(readGetters(SimpleTestObject.prototype));

// For instance
var instance = new SimpleTestObject();
console.log(readGetters(Object.getPrototypeOf(instance)));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can  enumerate setter/getter properties by `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` if you use getter and setter with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) or [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)

```
const _name = Symbol();
const _age = Symbol();

class Dog {

    constructor(name, age) {

        Object.defineProperties(this, {
            name: {
                // you can set enumerable true explicitly if you want
                //enumerable:true , 
                set(value) {
                    this[_name] = name;
                },
                get() {
                    return this[_name];
                }
            },

            age: {
                set(value) {
                    this[_age] = age;
                },
                get() {
                    return this[_age];
                }
            },
            book: {
                get() {
                    return "Book"
                }
            }
        });

        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }


}

const dog = new Dog("spike", 3);

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(dog));
```

Comment: That is a very unorthodox way of doing classical JavaScript. Using `defineProperties` will not set them onto the prototype and `getOwnPropertyNames` will also not pick up on prototypal getters. It's better to use `getOwnPropertyDescriptors` with either `Object.create` or the regular classical syntax.